# Parsing datetime from csv in pandas does not yield DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm exploring Pandas - trying to learn and apply it. Currently I have a csv file populated with a financial timeseries data of following structure:

`date, time, open, high, low, close, volume
2003.04.08,12:00,1.06830,1.06960,1.06670,1.06690,446
2003.04.08,13:00,1.06700,1.06810,1.06570,1.06630,433
2003.04.08,14:00,1.06650,1.06810,1.06510,1.06670,473
2003.04.08,15:00,1.06670,1.06890,1.06630,1.06850,556
2003.04.08,16:00,1.06840,1.07050,1.06610,1.06680,615`

Now I want to convert the csv data into a pandas DataFrame object, so that date and time fields merge and become the DateTimeIndex of the DataFrame like this:

```
df = pa.read_csv(path,
                 names = ['date', 'time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'vol'],
                 parse_dates = {'dateTime': ['date', 'time']},  
                 index_col = 'dateTime')
```

This works yielding a nice DataFrame object:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 8676 entries, 2003.04.08 12:00 to nan nan
Data columns (total 5 columns):
open     8675  non-null values
high     8675  non-null values
low      8675  non-null values
close    8675  non-null values
vol      8675  non-null values
dtypes: float64(5)
```

But upon inspection it turns out that the Index is not a DataTimeIndex but unicode strings instead:

```
type(df.index)
>>> pandas.core.index.Index
df.index
>>> Index([u'2003.04.08 12:00', u'2003.04.08 13:00', u'2003.04.08 14:00', ....
```

So `read_csv` parsed the date and time fields, merged them but did not create a DateTimeIndex. As far as I understood from the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html) a new datastructure object supplied with a list of datetime objects should automatically create a DateTimeIndex. Am I wrong? Is the DataFrame object an exception?

I also tried to convert the current index like this:

```
df.index = pa.to_datetime(df.index)
```

but no changes have been made to the index and it is still in unicode format. I begin to suspect the default parsing functions aren't doing their job, but I don't get any error messages from them.

How to get a working DateTimeIndex in a DateFrame in this situation?

**Solution:**

```
df = pa.read_csv(path,
                 names = ['date', 'time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'vol'],
                 parse_dates={'datetime':['date','time']},
                 keep_date_col = True, 
                 index_col='datetime'
             )
```

now apply the lambda function, doing what the parser should have done:

```
df['datetime'] = df.apply(lambda row: datetime.datetime.strptime(row['date']+ ':' + row['time'], '%Y.%m.%d:%H:%M'), axis=1)
```

Comment: Could you post the first few rows of the raw csv file? My guess is you'll need to specify a `date_parser` function to give to `read_csv`.

Comment: What happens if you try `df = pa.read_csv(path, names = ['date', 'time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'vol'], parse_dates = [['date', 'time']])` so don't explicitly name the combined datetime column, does this work?

Comment: @TomAugspurger added sample rows at the beginning of the question to show what the data looks like

Comment: @EdChum it still creates a merged date_time column and fills it with type object. The default integer index is applied i.e. pandas.core.index.Int64Index

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dateutil is unable to parse your data correctly but you can do it after loading like so using `strptime`:

```
import datetime
df['DateTime'] = df.apply(lambda row: datetime.datetime.strptime(row['date']+ ':' + row['time'], '%Y.%m.%d:%H:%M'), axis=1)
```

This will yield you the 'DateTime' column as `datetime64[ns]` and you can use it as your index

**EDIT**

Hmm.. interestingly when I do this it works:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\data\temp.txt', parse_dates={'datetime':['date','time']}, index_col='datetime')
```

Could you see what happens when you drop the column names from the parameters to `read_csv`

Comment: Finally your solution worked with applying a lambda worked. I had to additionally keep date and time columns by passing 'keep_date_col = True' to 'read_csv'.

Comment: @EmEs Glad it works, it is unclear why passing the columns fails except it produces a wierd dataframe with 2 level columns, this maybe the root of the problem